# Prove two inhabitants in Prop are not equal?

Tags: coq, proof, formal-verification

Is it possible to have some `A, B : Prop` such that we can provide a proof of:

```
Section QUESTION.
A: Prop := <whatever you want> .
B : Prop := <whatever you want> .
Theorem ANeqB: A <> B.
Proof.
<a proof of this fact>
Qed.
```

Intuitively, I think not, since this would let us "distinguish" between proofs, but one should not be able to do this without computing on `A` or `B`. However, Coq explicitly forbids us from inspecting a proof, since they must be erased at runtime. So, only `Prop` ought to be able to inspect `Prop` (due to erasure), but inspection is always computational, hence `Prop` cannot inspect `Prop`. Therefore, *nothing* can inspect `Prop`, and the above theorem `ANeqB` cannot be proved.

- If my above explanation is incorrect, could you please explain to me why it is so?
- If the theorem `ANeqB` cannot be proved, can you point me a proof of this fact?
- If the theorem `ANeqB` *can* be proved, can you tell me where my intuition fails?

EDIT:

It just struck me that since we can take proof irrelevance as an extra axiom (`Axiom proof_irrelevance : forall (P:Prop) (p1 p2:P), p1 = p2.`), the theorem `ANeqB` cannot be proven within Coq --- if it could, it would make it unsound to allow `proof_irrelevance` as an extra axiom.

This shifts my question, then:

- Is it possible to prove `ANeqB` for *some* inhabitants `A` and `B`? (`proof_irrelevance` is stronger: it states that we cannot prove `A <> B` [actually, the more stronger statement that we *can* prove `A = B`] for *all* `A, B`)
- If not, can someone furnish a proof that `ANeqB` *cannot be proved* in Coq's based axiomatic system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of something else. `Prop` itself isn't proof irrelevant. It definitely has distinguishable elements. For example, `True <> False`.

```
Section QUESTION.
Definition A: Prop := True.
Definition B : Prop := False.

Theorem ANeqB: A <> B.
Proof.
  unfold A, B.
  intro p.
  destruct p.
  exact I.
Qed.

End QUESTION.
```

Instead, it's *elements* of `Prop` that might be proof irrelevant. In the axiom

```
Axiom proof_irrelevance: forall (P: Prop) (p q: P), p = q.
```

`p` and `q` aren't themselves elements of `Prop`, but rather elements of some element of `Prop`.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question perfectly! I posted another question that you may have some insight on, if you're interested : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242486/provide-example-in-coq-where-a-b-prop-p-prop-prop-such-that-a-b-bu