# Provide example in Coq where (A B: Prop), P: Prop -> Type, such that A <-> B, but one cannot replace P A with P B

Tags: coq, proof, formal-verification

As the title asks, I wish for an example where:

```
Section Question:
Definition A: Prop := <whatever you like>.
Definition B:Prop := <whatever you like>.
Definition/Inductive/Fixpoint P: Prop -> Type := <whatever you like>.

Theorem AEquivB: A <-> B.
Proof. <supply proof here>. Qed.

(* Question 1. can we pick a P, A, B to prove this? *)
Theorem PA_not_equals_Pb: P A <> P B.
Proof. <supply proof here>. Qed.

(* Question 1.5. can we pick a P, A, B to prove this? *)
Theorem PA_not_equiv_PB: ~(P A <-> P B)
Proof. <supply proof here>. Qed.
```

In general, I am interested to understand whether "proof equivalence" is "good enough" to be used as "equality" in a sense, or whether there are situations where we can have `P A`, and `A <-> B`, but **not** `P B`.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered in Coq for meta-theoretical reasons.  The logic of Coq (usually named CIC) is not strong enough to reason about all the proofs that are describable in itself.  For instance, there are statements that cannot be proved, but their opposite cannot be proved either.  This is why Coq'wiki contains a [section about axioms](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/The-Logic-of-Coq) that are safe to add to Coq.  I did not find a direct answer to exactly your question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is consistent with Coq that `forall A B : Prop, (A <-> B) -> A = B`. (That is, you can add this as an axiom and the theory won't collapse.) This axiom is called [propositional extensionality](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/CoqAndAxioms#propositional-extensionality). As `A = B` quickly gives `forall P : Prop -> Prop, P A <-> P B`, there are no terms `P`, `A`, `B` such that `(A <-> B) /\ ~(P A <-> P B)`, since this would contradict the axiom, but we know it is consistent. Similarly, we also quickly get `P A = P B`, which means we cannot also get `P A <> P B`. Note that even though such `P`, `A`, `B` that violate propositional extensionality do not exist, we still cannot prove propositional extensionality. Coq simply doesn't have the strength to talk about itself like that (which is good, since that means you can customize it), which is why propositional extensionality needs to be added as an axiom if you want it.

Comment: Thank you; do you know where this was proven to be sound with Coq?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I think you could find a proof by starting in `ClassicalFacts` (which contains some facts about this axiom) and chasing some citations.